# Sort a List of objects by one of it`s fields (that contains list of Strings)

Tags: java, android, list, collections, comparator

I have a `List` of objects. Inside it I have another `List` of `Strings` (that contains numbers).

How can I order the `List` of objects, by the the numbers, that inside the `List` of `Strings`?

I tried to do something like that:

```
 Collections.sort(bets, new Comparator<Bet>() {
       public int compare(Bet b1, Bet b2) {
             return Integer.valueOf(b1.getPlayersHighScores().get(0))
        .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b2.getPlayersHighScores().get(0)));
       }
 });
 Collections.reverse(bets);
```

The main problem is that the `List` of bets may have one or more bets, but the `List` of `getPlayersHighScores` can contain many `Strings`.

Comment: Are the player highscores already ordered in a way that the highest score is on index zero?

Comment: @SubOptimal No, the first player is the initiator of the game....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why is the highscore a String if it contain a Number? Wouldn't it make more sense to make it Integer or some other Number?

Second, why do you keep a list of highscores? Doesn't it make more sense to retain only one highscore (the highest)?

Thirdly, by what property of the List of highscores would you order the Bets? As you've observed, just taking the first highscore for each bet doesn't make much sense. Would you want to order them by the max of each list? The sum? The avg?

Say you're going with sum, you then would only have to write you comparator something like (Java8):

```
new Comparator<Bet>() {
    public int compare(Bet b1, Bet b2) {
           return b1.getPlayersHighScores().stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum()
            .compareTo(b2.getPlayersHighScores()stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum());
         }
    }
```

Comment: You are absolutely right about the String, it wasn`t written by me. The thing is, that users play, and the one that have the highest score - takes the bet. Now, i want to show a list of all scores, so i want to sort them, by highest.

Comment: If you mean, you want to order the Bets by their highest highscore (ie, the max of their respective highscore-lists) then simply replace both instances of sum() in the above code with max().getAsInt()

Comment: No, sir, that is the problem, i need to arrange them by players score, not by Bets...

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure I understand you. Are you saying you want to concatenate all lists of highscores and then sort that new mega list-of-highscores?